# Highlight code line that edit into Netbeans 7.4 or 8.0

Tags: css, linux, netbeans, ide

Hell,
I'm working on Netbeans 7.4 
I have big files like **CSS** ... etc.
Some times my clients send me files to correct errors such like **CSS** files.
I looking for Netbeans plug-in that highlight the code lines that i edit it.
when i come back to file again easily see what lines worked on before.
How can i do this?
Thanks too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: Select two files in the Projects view, invoke context menu and go to Tools | Diff.

Comment: Good, but is there are any solution exist in same file?